# Store JSON in Core data (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing, core-data

i woud like to develop an app with a fixed database ( a database of films with dilution for development etc...). I have a JSON with all the films, what is the best way to store into core data?

I would like to:

- Parse JSON only at first time launch (or app reset) and save all the element into core data

This is what I am thinking to do:

- Parse JSON
- Assign it to an object (an array of objects) and add it into an array of [[String: Any]]
- Use NSBatchInsertRequest -> that need a [[String : Any]]

Is this a correct approach? Or there is a better and easier solution?

Comment: Core Data won't save `[[String : Any]]`. You need to create a data model, and your model objects must inherit from `NSManagedObject`. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1

Comment: I'll give a look, thanks! But I found this in the apple documentation under NSBatchInertRequest: init(entity: NSEntityDescription, objects: [[String : Any]])
Creates a batch-insertion request for a managed entity, and provides an array of data dictionaries for insertion.

Comment: Why the json, why not ship the app with all info in Core Data?

Comment: How this is done? Just manually filling the table?